How to get access to resource file with setup project?
I have a game project where I parse a .txt document into a List (method is called in ctor):
private List<string> ParseVocabulary(string path)
{
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        return stream
            .ReadToEnd()
            .Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToList();
    }
}

Then I've created a Setup project for this game. And after installing and running the shortcut on the desktop I get an error:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WG\WordsGameSetup\Resourses\citiesVocabulary.txt' is denied.

I've tried to run the .exe file in with admin rights and I don't get this error.
How can I run a shortcut without error and using admin rights?

A user says "I found that it reads without problem when the application is signed, or after UAC question when it is not signed." in a comment on Why I get Access denied when try to read file from ProgramFiles/MyApp?

You can simplify reading the file with private List<string> ParseVocabulary(string path) => File.ReadLines(path).ToList();

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I have the similar problem when I want to write a line to the file. I've tried this File.AppendAllText(Path, word + Environment.NewLine); and this using (var stream = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))) stream.WriteLine(word); but it doesn't work as well.
